# Using reduce with await give different result

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, async-await, reduce

I have one reduce with async function and another one without async, given the same arguments the result is different, I can't figure out why:

Example without async:

```js
function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}

const listOfMonths = [
  "2020-01",
  "2020-02",
  "2020-03",
  "2020-04",
  "2020-05",
  "2020-06"
];

const reduceWithoutAsync = listOfMonths.reduce(
        (previousKpis, curr, index) => {
          return {
            ...previousKpis,
            [curr]: "Hello Mars"
          };
        },
        {}
      );
      
output(JSON.stringify(reduceWithoutAsync, null, 4))
```

With Async:

```js
function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}

const listOfMonths = [
  "2020-01",
  "2020-02",
  "2020-03",
  "2020-04",
  "2020-05",
  "2020-06"
];

listOfMonths.reduce(async (previousKpis, curr, index) => {
  return Promise.resolve({
           ...previousKpis,
           [curr]: await Promise.resolve("hello Mars")
         });
    },
  Promise.resolve({})
).then(result => output(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)));
```

Why I'm only having the last element when I use the async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function output(inp) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
}

const listOfMonths = [
  "2020-01",
  "2020-02",
  "2020-03",
  "2020-04",
  "2020-05",
  "2020-06"
];

listOfMonths.reduce((previousKpis, curr, index) => (
        previousKpis.then(async prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [curr]: await Promise.resolve("hello Mars")
        }))
    ),
    Promise.resolve({})
).then(result => output(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)));
```

previousKpis is a Promise, so you need to either `await` it or use `then` as I did in my example. Everything should be fine then!

Answer (score 0):

Add `const previousKpis = await previousKpis` before your return statement.

Each function you provide to reduce is an async function which means it returns a promise. Even though you are calling return in that promise, you still need to await it. You are spreading previousKpis before it resolves, I believe.

Comment: same problem even with const